# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL though it executes doGet

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish-3

```
public class RoarHistoryUpdate extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException{
        super.doGet(request, response);
        System.out.println("do Get");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getOutputStream().print("Success");
    }
}
```

This is my Servlet. And it is registerd in the web.xml like this:

```
  <servlet>
      <display-name>RoarHistoryUpdateServlet</display-name>
      <servlet-name>RoarHistoryUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>de.ulm.uni.vs.avid.roary.servlets.RoarHistoryUpdate</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>RoarHistoryUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/Roary/UpdateServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I go to the URL `http://localhost:8080/Roary-JSP/Roary/UpdateServlet` It says `HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL`

Funny thing is I get the `do Get` logged to my console. So it actually found the `doGet`-method.

I am using a GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because when you do `super.doGet(request, response);` in your Servlet's `doGet()` method, you actually call the `doget()` of the `HttpServlet` class. The `Tomcat 7` implementation of that method is as below (may be a similar implementation exists for `Glassfish`):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String protocol = req.getProtocol();
    String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_get_not_supported");
    if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
    } else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats it. thanks!

Comment: Please mark it as answer,As its helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's because of invoking `super.doGet()`. If you check the source code of `HttpServlet`, you'll see that it sets this status code on the response. So drop the super call. It's not needed.