# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL - nothing printing to console

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httprequest, http-status-code-405

There are similar questions I've found, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370633/405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207536/http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url-thoug-it-executes-doget) but in both of them, results are being printed in the console while in my case, there's nothing.

The issue is, I have a Java Servlet subclass that I would like to print something to the browser screen. However, when I go the url the servlet is mapped to, it prints this to the screen:

[image: Apache Tomcat 405]

This is my Servlet subclass:

```
package instrurental_proj.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Bla extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 16252534;
    private static int ping = 3000;
    private Thread t;
    private static boolean shouldStop = false;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doGet");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><h1>It works!!</h1></html>");
    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("service");

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doPost");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Destroy servlet");
        shouldStop = true;
    }
}
```

and this is my `web.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Bla</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>instrurental_proj.servlets.Bla</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Bla</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bla</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

When I run the server, this is what the console prints out:

```
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 8\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\jetty\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25;C:\Users\Imray\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;.
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:instrurental_proj' did not find a matching property.
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 465 ms
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:36 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm startInternal
SEVERE: Exception opening database connection
java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:692)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5350)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:688)
    ... 11 more

Aug 31, 2014 12:50:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2014 12:50:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1617 ms
```

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us the right config and servlet? The code you've posted could not give a 405.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes 100% sure

Comment: Well...I don't see it. Open up your container logs and show us what it printed out.

Comment: Where do I find the container logs? Do you mean the console?

Comment: Yes, I mean the console. The logs of apache tomcat are in the installation directory under `/logs`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok I added the console output

Comment: Do you know what a `ClassNotFoundException` is? Have you tried to fix that first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60339/discussion-between-imray-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 0):

Seems there was an error in my `web.xml` file. Things started working better when I changed the header of my `web.xml` file from

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not org.postgresql.Driver in apache.

Choose your jdbc.jar

1. [JDBC3 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.3-1102](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar)
2. [JDBC4 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.3-1102](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar)
3. [JDBC41 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.3-1102](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar)

Add jdbc-version.jar to apache-tomcat-x.x.x\lib file.